# New dataframe column 'count' for each ID and less than the date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I want to add a new column called count which counts the no. of entries per ID less than the date.
This is how my data frame looks like

```
    date    ID     count
20191101 &nbsp; &nbsp;1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 1<br>
20191102 &nbsp; &nbsp;2 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 0<br>
20191030 &nbsp; &nbsp;1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 0<br>
20191103 &nbsp; &nbsp;2 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 1<br>
20191105 &nbsp; &nbsp;2 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 2<br>
20191030 &nbsp; &nbsp;1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 0<br>
```

My dataframe has 15 columns and 90k rows

Comment: Could you show an example of what the output would look like given the sample here?

Comment: My dataframe has 'date' and 'ID' field and I want to add 'count' column

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, sort and cumsum is what you need

```
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'date'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
df1['cumulative_count'] = df1.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['count'].cumsum()
df1
    ID  date    count   cumulative_count
0   1   20191030    0   0
1   1   20191101    1   1
2   2   20191102    0   0
3   2   20191103    1   1
4   2   20191105    2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df =  df.sort_values(by=['ID','date'])
df['count'] = 1
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID')['count'].transform('cumsum')
df['final'] = df['cumsum'] - 1 

       date  ID  count  cumsum  final
2  20191030   1      1       1      0
5  20191030   1      1       2      1
0  20191101   1      1       3      2
1  20191102   2      1       1      0
3  20191103   2      1       2      1
4  20191105   2      1       3      2
```

The `final` is the column you need, the rest are just helper columns that can be discarded